# ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

Tags: asp.net, html, sql, sockets, odbc

My university's website always crashes every day at this time of day and it remains crashed for 2-3 hours, and it gives this error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>
> [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N A communication error has been detected.
>   Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP". Communication API being
>   used: "SOCKETS". Location where the error was detected: "10.13.41.10".
>   Communication function detecting the error: "connect". Protocol
>   specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*". SQLSTATE=08001
>
> /students/INDEX.ASP, line 110

and I am wondering what causes this error? Is it a code-bug? or is it something else? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets error 10061 means that the machine refused the connection.  This usually means that there is no application listening on the specified port.

If it's happening at the same time every day, I would hazard a guess that there is some kind of scheduled maintenance going on on the database server (perhaps a backup?).